# Unable to have a command line parameter in Python

Tags: python

I run

```
import sys

print "x \tx^3\tx^3+x^3\t(x+1)^3\tcube+cube=cube+1"

for i in range(sys.argv[2]):              // mistake here
    cube=i*i*i
    cube2=cube+cube
    cube3=(i+1)*(i+1)*(i+1)
    truth=(cube2==cube3)

    print i, "\t", cube, "\t", cube + cube, "\t", cube3, "\t", truth
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cube.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in range(sys.argv[2]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**How can you use command line parameter as follows in the code?**

**Example of the use**

```
python cube.py 100
```

It should give

```
x   x^3 x^3+x^3 (x+1)^3 cube+cube=cube+1
0   0   0   1   False
1   1   2   8   False
2   8   16  27  False
--- cut ---
97  912673  1825346     941192  False
98  941192  1882384     970299  False
99  970299  1940598     1000000     False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest having a look at Python's [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module, which is a giant improvement in parsing commandline parameters - it can also do the conversion to `int` for you including type-checking and error-reporting / generation of help messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please, consider adding the code how to do this in 3.2. It seems to be basicly **for i in range(sys.argv[1])** just without the type conversion.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
sys.argv[1]
```

also note that arguments are always strings, and `range` expects an integer.

So the correct code would be:

```
for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])):
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `int(sys.argv[1])` not 2.

Ideally you would check the length of sys.argv first and print a useful error message if the user doesn't provide the proper arguments.

Edit: See http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_commandline.html

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips on how you can often solve this type of problem *yourself*:

Read what the error message is telling you: "list index out of range".

What list? Two choices (1) the list returned by range (2) sys.argv

In this case, it can't be (1); it's impossible to get that error out of
`for i in range(some_integer)` ... but you may not know that, so in general, if there are multiple choices within a line for the source of an error, and you can't see which is the cause, split the line into two or more statements:

```
num_things = sys.argv[2]
for i in range(num_things):
```

and run the code again.

By now we know that sys.argv is the list. What index? Must be 2. How come that's out of range? Knowledge-based answer: Because Python counts list indexes from 0. Experiment-based answer: Insert this line before the failing line:

```
print list(enumerate(sys.argv))
```

So you need to change the [2] to [1]. Then you will get another error, because in range(n) the n must be an integer, not a string ... and you can work through this new problem in a similar fashion -- extra tip: look up range() in the docs.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I now see what was my problem: I searched Python-doc by the keywords "parameter" and "arg" without finding range's parameter type. It is clearly best to search the Python docs at least in this case with "range".

Comment: John explains very nicely how to debug such things, I'd like to add that an interactive Python shell (preferably iPython) can be of great help for figuring out how specific parts work...

Answer (score 1):

Its sys.argv[1] instead of 2. You also want to makes sure that you convert that to an integer if you're doing math with it.

so instead of

```
for i in range(sys.argv[2]):
```

you want

```
for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])):
```